# A system issue occurred in facebook account kit

Tags: account-kit

i could not resolve facebook account kit (A system issue occurred. please try again) issue even i have enabled client token access and sms login in account kit developers account.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to Login With Account Kit and Try to Generate:-

1- the AccessToken Code 
you must Enable the 
**Client Access Token Flow** and set  `new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(LoginType.PHONE, AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);`

2- the Authorization Code 
you must Disable the **Client Access Token Flow** and and set  `new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(LoginType.PHONE, AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE);`

Answer (score 3):

Please check the **Client Token** it is exactly the same as on dashboard!!
Also check the manifest file do you properly add the **Account kit activity and meta data of Account kit**.

If again having problem feel free to ask..
Thanks.

Comment: I just changed request codes of Google login and facebook account kit, actually onActivitystart start method getting same request codes thats why its not giving me exact response, thanks to you man for answer

Comment: ok that's good you debug your problem.
Whenever you need help provide the code to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN from **string.xml**

ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN using the client token found in the Account Kit tab in the App Dashboard.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/***FB_APP_ID***/account-kit/settings/

In above url replace ***FB_APP_ID*** to your application id[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet, when you are clicking on next, if the internet is not there, then you will face this error apart from client access token not being given

Answer (score 0):

**Go To Products Tab--> Setting -->  Server Side Validation is Enabled**

1). Allow Email Login **Yes**

2). Allow Phone Number Login **Yes**

3). Enable Client Access Token Flow  **Yes**

4). Require App Secret **No**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just because u might not be removed **[]** those brackets... i did the same thing. then i had found this syntax error

this is wrong-->
`<string name="ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN">[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA]</string>`

this is right-->(**no BRACKETS**)

`<string name="ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</string>`